# Floating hint in TextInputLayout moving upwards as soon as we click on editTextView

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout inside which I have an EditTextView where I have set a hint.
As soon as I click on editTextView, the hint move upwards.

I want it to start floating or move upwards when user starts typing something..Till the time user doesn't type anything it should display hint as usual.

Could anyone tell me the best way to do this?